# Meaning of "it will do you in"?

Tags: meaning

What is the meaning of the expression "it will do you in"? I came across this sentence: if you are not careful, it will do you in.

Comment: [do someone in](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/do?q=do+you+in#do__115)

Answer (score 2):

**to do in** Slang

1. To tire completely; exhaust: The marathon did me in.
2. To kill.
3. To ruin utterly: Huge losses on the stock market did many investors in.

Source: Collins Dictionary

It depends on the context from which the  sentence was taken, any of the three meanings may fit  in your case.

Comment: I think '2' is perhaps the original meaning, and '1' and '2' metaphorical. It would not be unusual to hear 'the marathon killed me'.

Answer (score 0):

It will do you in implies - to destroy, to reduce or even cause of destruction

Answer (score -1):

It will do you in means it will kill you.

Comment: Does it mean "kill you" in a literal sense?

Comment: @Ambika People certainly use it in that way, particularly as regards suicide - 'she did herself in'. But as others have commented it is used in other ways, I believe metaphorically.